# Why load url from sd card does not work in android ICS using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hello i am developing an Android app based on phonegap, i am using cordova 2.0, when i try to load the index file from sd card it shows A Netwrok Error Occurred and does not load the file, but this only happens with ICS but it's working on 3.0 and lower

when i load the file from assets it works fine but the problem is when i load it from sd card

here is my code `public class ApplicationView extends DroidGap {
    WebView appWebView;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    String destDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/DroidLibrary/leftbankappunzipped/www/LeftBankInt/index.html";

    String url = "file:///" + destDirectory;

    super.init();
    super.clearCache();
    super.clearHistory();
    super.loadUrl(url,10000);

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

have you given the read storage permission in the manifest file.

```
<permission name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</permission>
```

[Permissions Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Answer (score 0):

I ever ran into this problem, then at the end found that's because of an unexpected code line, a call to

```
WebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);
```

See if this helps to your case.

Comment: @f1lt3r, this is a story in long time ago, I don't have that copy of code now, so sorry I can't tell the repo/file/line.